# How to switch between applications using Python

Tags: python, automation

Within my current internship, there is a certain task that requires the following to be done:

1. Copy a cell within an Excel file
2. Paste the cell's value within a Web Application
3. Click on an "Add" button

To automate this process, I recently created a macro using a 3rd party software. However, I now wish to do this using code. For this, I am using Python.

I believe I have the majority done by using selenium and pyautogui; however, switching between Excel and Chrome has proven to be a hassle. What is the method one uses to complete such a task? Thank you in advance! I am a very amateur coder here.

Comment: "Switching applications" is really only something that make sense in a GUI. Communication between two processes doesn't need to make use of the GUI, though. Python can read the Excel file directly, without using Excel, and it could submit a query to the web application without actually using your web browser as the interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to actually use Excel.
You can use https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/ and https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/ to read and write from an xlsx file or use https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html for CSV files.
Using chrome can be done through Selenium, or even generate a request using the requests module